# Accessing SWI-Prolog libraries from Logtalk

Tags: prolog, dcg, logtalk

I'm having a lot of fun using Logtalk, but ran into an issue using `phrase_from_file`. Specifically, my case looks something like this:

```
:- object(scan_parser).

   :- public(scanlist//1).
   scanlist([Scan|Scans]) --> scan(Scan), dcg_basics:blanks, scanlist(Scans).
   scanlist([]) --> [].

   :- public(scan_file/2).
   :- mode(scan_file(+filename, -scans), one).
   scan_file(Filename, Scans) :- pio:phrase_from_file(scanlist(Scans), Filename).

   ...
:- end_object.
```

The trouble is all in that call to `phrase_from_file`. It's unable to find `scanlist`, presumably because it is local to this object, so I get this error:

```
?- scan_parser::scan_file('input.txt', Scans).
ERROR: phrase/3: Undefined procedure: pio:scanlist/3
```

But, if I try to aggrandize it with a module reference like so:

```
scan_file(Filename, Scans) :- pio:phrase_from_file(::scanlist(Scans), Filename).
```

I get this error:

```
?- scan_parser::scan_file('input.txt', Scans).
ERROR: phrase/3: Undefined procedure: pio: (::)/3
```

Same if I use `pio:phrase_from_file(this::scanlist(Scans), Filename)` or `pio:phrase_from_file(scan_parser::scanlist(Scans), Filename)`. If I use a single colon instead in emulation of SWI's module facility, I get messages like `ERROR: phrase/3: Undefined procedure: scan_parser:scanlist/3`.

I assume that the problem here is that SWI's PIO library is trying to construct something to hand to `phrase` and it's just not intelligent enough. But this is something that comes up for me a lot, using `phrase_from_file/2`, and I'm sure there will be other times I want to excavate something from SWI's library and borrow it. What's the right way forward? I'd like to preserve the encapsulation of Logtalk as much as possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Daniel. Which Logtalk version are you using?

Comment: I'm using 2.44.1, but I will try against 3.0 if you think it may not be a problem there. You may also need to create 'input.txt' before the error becomes evident.

Comment: I strongly suggest that you move to Logtalk 3.x. But you stumble on a Logtalk limitation (which is independent of the version you use): module meta-predicates that take closures are not supported (see the Prolog migration section on the User Manual). Let me think for a moment on a alternative solution, however.

Comment: Same behavior under 3.0 HEAD.

Comment: The root of the problem is that Logtalk compiles object predicates by (among other transformations) adding a single argument at the end (used to pass the execution context). This clashes with using module meta-predicates that take closures as the module will (usually with a direct or indirect call to call/N) append the additional arguments to go from a closure to a goal and the hidden execution context argument will be caught in the middle (Prolog module systems are not Logtalk-aware).

Comment: Btw, I tried to simply compile them module "pio" as an object but the chain of dependencies (some of them undeclared and some containing SWI-Prolog only proprietary stuff) for this module makes that hard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm designing a general solution for Logtalk 3.x to support Prolog module meta-predicates that take closures as meta-arguments. Meanwhile, can you try the following (ugly) workaround:

```
% ensure the module is loaded
:- use_module(library(pio)).


:- object(scan_parser).

    % override the non-standard meta-arguments declarations
    :- meta_predicate(pio:phrase_from_file(2,*)).

   :- public(scanlist//1).
   scanlist([Scan|Scans]) --> scan(Scan), dcg_basics:blanks, scanlist(Scans).
   scanlist([]) --> [].

   :- public(scan_file/2).
   :- mode(scan_file(+filename, -scans), one).
   scan_file(Filename, Scans) :- pio:phrase_from_file(user:scan_parser_scanlist(Scans), Filename).

    {scan_parser_scanlist(Scans, A, B)} :-
        phrase(scanlist(Scans), A, B).

    ...

:- end_object.
```

I cannot test as you only posted part of the object code.

Comment: Thanks! I am happy to have a workaround in case I run into other similar situations.

Comment: The just updated Logtalk 3.x HEAD should provide you with faster generated code for (:)/2 non-terminals as in the code you posted.

Comment: The limitation described above (regarding calling Prolog module meta-predicates that take closures as meta-arguments) is lifted in the latest Logtalk 3.x HEAD.

Comment: Logtalk 3.00.0 Alpha 17 include the changes to support calling from within object and categories both Prolog built-in meta-predicates and Prolog module meta-predicates that take closures as meta-arguments. The code you posted should work as-is without needing any workaround.